# Summarizing a dataframe using a reference column

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

Consider the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(waypoint = 1:10, pnt1 = NA, pnt2 = NA, pnt3 = NA)

x <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

df$pnt1 <- as.factor(sample(x, 10, replace = T))
df$pnt2 <- as.factor(sample(x, 10, replace = T))
df$pnt3 <- as.factor(sample(x, 10, replace = T))

df
```

I'd like to summarize this dataframe in the following manner, where the values from the "pnt1, pnt2, and pnt3" columns in the original df are summed for each waypoint and placed into new columns "A, B, C, D". The shell of the result would look like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(waypoint = 1:10, A = NA, B = NA, C = NA, D = NA)
```

How can I code this to produce a result similar to df2 that is filled with the correct values?

Comment: You would like to count the number of every letter per row?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("pnt")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = waypoint,
              names_from = value,
              values_from = value,
              values_fn = length,
              values_fill = 0L,
              names_sort = T)
```

**Output**

```
   waypoint     A     B     C     D
      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1        1     2     0     0     1
 2        2     0     1     1     1
 3        3     1     0     2     0
 4        4     3     0     0     0
 5        5     2     1     0     0
 6        6     1     2     0     0
 7        7     2     0     1     0
 8        8     1     2     0     0
 9        9     0     1     1     1
10       10     1     1     0     1
```

**Data**

With `set.seed(1)`:

```
structure(list(waypoint = 1:10, pnt1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    pnt2 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), pnt3 = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", 
    "C"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely use Base R here.

```
table(cbind(df[1], " "=unlist(df[-1])))
         
waypoint A B C D
      1  2 0 0 1
      2  0 1 1 1
      3  1 0 2 0
      4  3 0 0 0
      5  2 1 0 0
      6  1 2 0 0
      7  2 0 1 0
      8  1 2 0 0
      9  0 1 1 1
      10 1 1 0 1
```

or even

```
xtabs(~waypoint+pnt, reshape(df, -1, dir="long", sep=""))
           pnt
waypoint   A B C D
      1  2 0 0 1
      2  0 1 1 1
      3  1 0 2 0
      4  3 0 0 0
      5  2 1 0 0
      6  1 2 0 0
      7  2 0 1 0
      8  1 2 0 0
      9  0 1 1 1
      10 1 1 0 1
```

If you need a dataframe, then wrap the whole code with `as.data.frame.matrix` function

Answer (score 2):

Library janitor also helps

```
set.seed(1)
df <- structure(list(waypoint = 1:10, pnt1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), pnt2 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L ), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), pnt3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")



library(janitor) 
library(tidyverse)

df%>% pivot_longer(-waypoint)  %>% tabyl(waypoint, value)

waypoint A B C D
        1 2 0 0 1
        2 0 1 1 1
        3 1 0 2 0
        4 3 0 0 0
        5 2 1 0 0
        6 1 2 0 0
        7 2 0 1 0
        8 1 2 0 0
        9 0 1 1 1
       10 1 1 0 1
```

Comment: Good one! I've never used janitor so far, but it seems like a very cool package.

Comment: For getting xtabs or excel type pivot tables summaries it is indeed a very good package

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(map_dfc(list(Count_A = "A",
                      Count_B = "B", 
                      Count_C = "C", 
                      Count_D = "D"), ~ sum(cur_data() == .x))) %>%
  select(-c(pnt1, pnt2, pnt3)) %>%
  rename_with(~ str_remove(., fixed("Count_")), starts_with("Count_"))


set.seed(1)

   waypoint     A     B     C     D
      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1        1     2     0     0     1
 2        2     0     1     1     1
 3        3     1     0     2     0
 4        4     3     0     0     0
 5        5     2     1     0     0
 6        6     1     2     0     0
 7        7     2     0     1     0
 8        8     1     2     0     0
 9        9     0     1     1     1
10       10     1     1     0     1
```